# c# - Unable to use rectangle in new class

Tags: c#, wpf

New to C# and probably a very basic question. This is the scenario.

I have created a WPF project and coded everything and all is working fine. I want to tidy up the codes by creating a new class and transfer all the methods over there instead of chalking it all up in the main class. But when I go to the newly created class, I can't access any of the information. For example I have a rectangle and named it "rect1". I am not able to find this rect1 in the newly formed class.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? The main class file reads as MainWindow.xaml.cs where everything is working fine. I create a new class within the same project with the file name Images.cs where the codes are not working. Even creating an instance of a class such as:

```
private SolidColorBrush red = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0));
```

returns as error. Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: What is the error returned? They are often quite descriptive of the problem and even if you don't understand what it is saying I am sure people here will be able to help much more with the full error message.

Comment: Is this `rect1` part of XAML code? In that case the member is automatically created and can not be moved to another class.

Comment: rect1 is a name I gave to a rectangle I drew as follows:<Rectangle Canvas.Left="26" Canvas.Top="47" Height="109" Name="rect1" Stroke="Black" Width="122" Fill="#FF50DDE8" />

Comment: Yes. In that case, you didn't "draw" a rectangle. You put a `Shape` control on the canvas. A member variable for that is automatically created. Of course it is not present in any other class, as it is exclusive to the class that's code behind for the XAML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get an error in this line

```
private SolidColorBrush red = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0));
```

I'm pretty sure you forgot to import the required namespaces and need to add

```
using System.Windows.Media;
```

to the top of the file.

---

About `rect1` not being present: It's a "component" you added in your XAML. So automatically a member variable is declared in the code-behind class. This variable is *only available*  in that class.

If in your new class you want to do something on `rect1`, you need to create the method so that it takes a parameter to which you can pass `rect1` (or any other rectangle).

```
public void DoSomethingOnRect(Rectangle r)
{
    ...
}
```

And then call it using:

```
helperInstace.DoSomethingOnRect(rect1);
```

And yes, this is the only valid way to do this. Never *EVER* try to make the `rect1` variable public in your code-behind class and access it.

Answer (score 0):

you may have declared the methods in the new class as private method. try to change it to 'public'.

Comment: When I attempt to create:                                                private SolidColorBrush green = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 0)); The error returns as: type could not be found. are you missing directive/assembly reference?

Comment: Add `using System.Windows.Media;` to the top of the class file.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten, the SolidColorBrush is recognized now. But still unable to recognize the rectangle I named as "rect1" at my MainWindow.xaml file in my new class images.cs.

Comment: That's because it is not there! It exists in XAML and the environment thankfully creates a member variable for it in the code behind file automatically. It is not present in new classes! What you can do is have your new method take a parameter of type `Rectangle` and then pass `rect1` when calling it. I'll edit my answer.